# Cannot display data in mat-table from array returned from service

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material, angularfire2

Can someone help me with angular material table?
Getting data from firebase, it shows if I use snapshotChanges() but data doesn't appear when I return array with custom data.

```
let prdarr= [];
this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
 .subscribe(products => {
     products.forEach(prddata => {
     let prd: any = prddata.payload.val();
     prdarr.push({
        PID: prddata.key,
        Name: prd.name,
     });
   });
});
return prdarr;
```

This works fine

```
return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges();
```

Markup

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
            <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
                <div class="example-element-diagram">
                    <div class="example-element-position"> {{element.position}} </div>
                    <div class="example-element-symbol"> {{element.symbol}} </div>
                    <div class="example-element-name"> {{element.name}} </div>
                    <div class="example-element-weight"> {{element.weight}} </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example-element-description">
                    {{element.description}}
                    <span class="example-element-description-attribution"> -- Wikipedia </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
    class="example-element-row"
    [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
    (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous. So basicly when you return the array firebase hasn't finished getting the data. I currently don't have the energy to help you more but if you search for this you will find plenty of information about how to handle this.

Comment: Share the template file.

Comment: @AndréKool I thought of that but I console logged in the array in the component, I am getting the data. only difference being [] instead of (2)[{...},{...}] but I am getting the required data if I check the array. Don't know if I'm missing something or I don't understand the depth of it. It would be great if you could help me fix it.

Comment: @leopal I have added the markup